# Using tidyverse to randomly get means from conditions

Tags: r

I have a long format data frame that looks like this:
[image]

What I'd like to do is (1) randomly split the trials from Condition 1 into 4 groups and then calculate the mean of Y for each ID and (2) carry out this same procedure for the trials in Condition 2. This is what this new output would look like:

[image]

Is there a concise way to do this using the tidyverse? I'm just getting started and am having a having a hard time with this!

Comment: How big is your original data frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your data frame is not that small, this should do exactly what you need.

```
set.seed(2)
df <- tibble(ID = c(rep(1,50),rep(2,50)),
       Condition = rep(c(1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2),5),
       Y = rnorm(100,100,20)) ##Creates some fake data



result_df <- df %>% mutate(randomizer = sapply(1:length(row_number()), function(i)sample(c(1,2,3,4),1))) %>%
  group_by(Condition) %>%
  group_by(ID, Condition, randomizer) %>%
  summarize(mean_y = mean(Y, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(condition_status = paste0("Condition",Condition,"M",randomizer)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  dplyr::select(-Condition, -randomizer) %>%
  spread(condition_status, mean_y)


result_df
```

Comment: are you only using the tidyverse package? I ask because I run this code and get the error "Error in select(., -Condition, -randomizer) : 
  unused arguments (-Condition, -randomizer)". Wondering if this might go away if I loaded another package.

Comment: Yes, this was done using tidyverse. There is probably a conflict with the select function. Use dplyr::select(-Condition, -randomizer). Will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

Not the best way but it does work

```
x <- data.frame(c(rep(1,10), rep(2,10)), c(1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2), c(100,200,80,58,89,100,200,80,58,89,95,72,99,120,130,95,72,99,120,130))
colnames(x) <- c("ID", "Condition", "Y")
id <- unique(x[,1])
con <- unique(x[,2])
#multiple by the number of groups to split into
y <- data.frame(matrix(, ncol = (length(id) * 4) + 1, nrow = length(id)))
y[,1] <- id
colnames(y) <- c("ID", "Condition1M1", "Condition1M2", "Condition1M3", "Condition1M4", "Condition2M1", "Condition2M2", "Condition2M3", "Condition2M4")
x1 <- x[which(x[,2] == con[1]),]
x2 <- x[which(x[,2] == con[2]),]
#specify sample size
n <- 5
x11 <- x1[sample(nrow(x1), n, replace = FALSE),]
x12 <- x1[sample(nrow(x1), n, replace = FALSE),]
x13 <- x1[sample(nrow(x1), n, replace = FALSE),]
x14 <- x1[sample(nrow(x1), n, replace = FALSE),]
x21 <- x2[sample(nrow(x2), n, replace = FALSE),]
x22 <- x2[sample(nrow(x2), n, replace = FALSE),]
x23 <- x2[sample(nrow(x2), n, replace = FALSE),]
x24 <- x2[sample(nrow(x2), n, replace = FALSE),]

y[1,2] <- mean(x11[which(x11[,1] == id[1]),3])
y[1,3] <- mean(x12[which(x12[,1] == id[1]),3])
y[1,4] <- mean(x13[which(x13[,1] == id[1]),3])
y[1,5] <- mean(x14[which(x14[,1] == id[1]),3])
y[2,2] <- mean(x21[which(x21[,1] == id[2]),3])
y[2,3] <- mean(x22[which(x22[,1] == id[2]),3])
y[2,4] <- mean(x23[which(x23[,1] == id[2]),3])
y[2,5] <- mean(x24[which(x24[,1] == id[2]),3])
y[1,6] <- mean(x11[which(x11[,1] == id[1]),3])
y[1,7] <- mean(x12[which(x12[,1] == id[1]),3])
y[1,8] <- mean(x13[which(x13[,1] == id[1]),3])
y[1,9] <- mean(x14[which(x14[,1] == id[1]),3])
y[2,6] <- mean(x21[which(x21[,1] == id[2]),3])
y[2,7] <- mean(x22[which(x22[,1] == id[2]),3])
y[2,8] <- mean(x23[which(x23[,1] == id[2]),3])
y[2,9] <- mean(x24[which(x24[,1] == id[2]),3])
```

Results:

```
  ID Condition1M1 Condition1M2 Condition1M3 Condition1M4 Condition2M1 Condition2M2 Condition2M3 Condition2M4
1  1     133.3333          100          150     133.3333     133.3333          100          150     133.3333
2  2     125.0000          125          125     120.0000     125.0000          125          125     120.0000
```